# MongoDB $geoIntersects does not match LineString type

Tags: mongodb, geojson, geo

I have a Mongo collection on which I am trying to perform a $geoIntersects query.

The data in mongo is in the form of:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "created_at" : ISODate,
    "sentiment" : 0.631925,
    "yyyy-mm" : "2012-9",
    "lat_lon" : [
        -2.0566385,
        52.84265
    ]
}
```

Running a $geoIntersects query in the form of:

```
db.gbSmall.findOne({
    lat_lon: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-2.0566385,52.84265]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

or

```
db.gbSmall.findOne({
    lat_lon: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: [[-2.0566385,52.84265],[-3.0566385,52.84265]]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

both properly return the record; however, if I change the query so the line runs through the point, such as:

```
db.gbSmall.findOne({
    lat_lon: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: [[-1.0566385,52.84265],[-3.0566385,52.84265]]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

the record is not returned.

Does a record have to fall on a point of a geoJSON lineString to be matched, or is there something else wrong with the query I am performing?

Comment: I can confirm your results. Interesting question. I had a go using number with no decimal places, such as does the line [-3,50] to [-1,50] intersect the point [-2,50], and nothing was returned. My guess is that it has to do with rounding precision. I have had a quick look at the source code, but to no avail, as I am no c++ guru.

Comment: Did you get any further with this. I had a good look at the source code until my head spun, but I'm reasonably sure it is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the same query in Postgis, you get the answer true.

```
Select ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2.0566385 52.84265)', 4326),
 ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-1.0566385 52.84265,-3.0566385 52.84265)', 4326));
```

You also get the same answer for a similar sanity check query:

```
Select ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2 50)',4326),
 ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-3 50, -1 50)',4326));
```

whereas both the MongoDB versions return nothing for the equivalent queries you gave above.

To me this looks like a bug. I checked the MongoDB source code and their tests and there isn't one for point on line except with end points. The MongoDB intersects functions found in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/geo/geoquery.cpp actually use the 3rd party s2 module to do the actual mathematical intersections, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/third_party/s2/s2latlngrect.cc. That is as far as I have got.

I am not posing this as an answer, as I don't have one, but the formatting is nicer than in comments.

Comment: Has the bug been fixed in Mongo?

Comment: @KoustavChanda, I don't know, I don't work on MongoDB anymore.